# Unable instantiate EventHubsSourceProvider in Azure databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I am trying to read the data from event hub from Azure Databricks using the following code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

NAMESPACE_NAME = "*myEventHub*"
KEY_NAME = "*MyPolicyName*"
KEY_VALUE = "*MySharedAccessKey*"

connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://{0}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={1};SharedAccessKey={2};EntityPath=ingestion".format(NAMESPACE_NAME, KEY_NAME, KEY_VALUE)

ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = connectionString

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()
```

It's throwing this error

`java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceProvider could not be instantiated`

I am using Databricks runtime version 14.2 (Scala 2.12, Spark 3.5.0)
and installed com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.22 package.
Please can someone help to resolve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the current package and restart the cluster. Install the package once again and try to run the code with the encrypted connection string as given below.

```py
connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://{0}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={1};SharedAccessKey={2};EntityPath=jgsevents".format(NAMESPACE_NAME, KEY_NAME, KEY_VALUE)

ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
```

Output:

```py
df.select(col("body").cast("string")).display()
```

| body |
| --- |
| [ { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3", "nestedKey": { "nestedKey1": "nestedValue1" }, "arrayKey": [ "arrayValue1", "arrayValue2" ] }] |

For more information, refer to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md#linking).

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS, I tried your suggestion but it's giving me this error org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt does not exist in the JVM
Please can you help. Thanks

Comment: You restarted the cluster?

Comment: How you are installing `azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.22 ` through maven repo or jar?

Comment: I restarted the cluster and installed the above package through maven

Comment: Use above code to encrypt connection string `sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)`

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS, I have used the same code to encrypt and it's giving me this error 
org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt does not exist in the JVM

Comment: This error raises when there is issue with library. Have you tried any other library `azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11`?

Comment: I have tried azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11 and it's giving me this error java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceProvider could not be instantiated.
My Databricks runtime version 14.2 (Scala 2.12, Spark 3.5.0)

Comment: Whenever you install new package it will create conflict between old installed packages.

Comment: Need to restart the cluster after uninstalling older one `azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.22 `

Comment: My scala version is 2.12. Will 2.11 work? Shouldn't it be azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.22 to be compatible?

Comment: I have uninstalled eventhubs-spark_2.12 and installed 2.11 and it's still the same error org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt does not exist in the JVM

Comment: Provide screenshot of libraries tab in databricks workspace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256518/discussion-between-sparc-and-jayashankargs).